# Last from a bunch of the infinite Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an Event Emitter which randomly emits values. It can stay idle for a few seconds, then emit 1-5 values, after that becomes idle till the new bunch on values. How can I take the latest of the bunch from the stream?

Example. Imagine one dot is one second. I'd like to take those values which were emitted no longer than 4 sec from previous value.

........ 1.3..5...........6..3.2.1...9.........4.......

How can I get values 5, 9 and 4? 
PS: I've tried bufferTime, debouceTime with no success.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "bigger delay value", just to clarify, I'm guessing you weren't passing in time values in terms of milliseconds.

Here's a link to the official docs for those who prefer text over video: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounceTime

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is .... `debounceTime(delay)` with bigger delay value than I assumed :-)
[Watch a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbNUD5ca99A)